# LoaderImageView zoom option not working

Tags: android, url, imageview, zooming

I displayed Image from the web.
For xml I used below code:

main.xml:

```
<com.imloader.LoaderImageView
        android:id="@+id/loaderImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        image="http://clients.redesignbox.com/honest/images/audi.jpg"/>
```

I want to put zoom functionality for that image>?
I knew the zoom functionality for zoom that I applied here.but here I used ***LoaderImageView.***

So, the imageview zoom functionality not working for me.
what is the process to apply zooming functionality here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please scale the matrix on the touch event of imageview and then set matrix to imageview it will work 
fine